# SetSubmitting is not a function

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have this `Formik` form that I integrated in a modal. What i try to do with it is pretty simple: assign some data from a user to another user.

Basically I have this onSubmit function that expects `setSubmitting` as a parameter.

```
  const handleSubmit = ({ setSubmitting }) => {
    assignAndMove(props.request);
    setSubmitting(false);
    props.handleClose();
  };
```

This is how my `Formik` `onSubmit` looks:

```
<Formik
  validationSchema={schema}
  onSubmit={({ setSubmitting }) => {
    console.log("args:", arguments);
    handleSubmit({setSubmitting});
  }}
>
```

and this is the `onSubmit` from my from:

```
<Form
  noValidate
  onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    handleSubmit(setSubmitting);
  }}
>
```

The problem is that I fail to call `setSubmitting(false)` from my `handleSubmit` function.

I get this error: `Formik.tsx:824 Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() TypeError: setSubmitting is not a function`

Any tips are welcomed. Thanks in advance!